# Python: Wtforms in pypugjs radio field doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, validation, pug, wtforms

I'm building a form with wtforms.
There is a radio field. Here is its data:

```
[(0, 'Active'),(1, 'Inactive'),]
```

I render the field in pypugjs:

```
input(type='radio', name=key, value=option_key, checked=(record_data[key]==option_key))=option_value
```

After the submitssion, i got `Not a valid choice` error.
But after changing choices to string value (1->'1')

```
[('0', 'Active'),('1', 'Inactive'),]
```

Now it works with Wtforms validation, so it means i have to use string as radio value in `RadioField`?

Then there is the new trouble: I couldn't get pypugjs field checked
even after use condition to check equal value

```
if record_data[key]==option_key
    |matched
```

It doesn't work even the result of `|#{record_data[key]}-#{option_key}-` is `1-1-`

So it means pypugjs doesn't match two same values, because one is Integer, one is String ?!

How do i get it work?

Answer (score 0):

The [RadioField](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.RadioField) class takes a `coerce` parameter which defines a function that is applied to the value received in the POST request.  The default `coerce` function for `RadioField` is `unicode`, so the field's value is  a string, but you can use `int` instead so that you get an integer.

```
class Foo(wtforms.Form):

    bar = wtforms.RadioField(coerce=int, choices=[(0, 'active'), (1, 'inactive')])
```